# Vector of pointers; losing values after function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, vector

I am tearing my hair out over this. Please can someone help me?

I have a C++ class with a vectors which stores objects. I have a function which needs to run every time a certain event happens, which should get the last element in the vector and get a property of it. The first time this function runs, there will obviously be no elements in the vector, so this function says, if it can't find an element, create one and add it to the vector. It does this using the `new` operator to create it in dynamically-allocated memory and then push_back()s the pointer to this object into the vector.

If, after immediately push_back()ing the object I get it with back(), then I can print out the properties fine. However, the second time the function runs, it's getting the properties as empty strings (they are all strings).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? My understanding was that doing it with the new operator will cause the item to be maintained. I have also tried without the `new` operator and having a vector of the objects rather than pointers - the EXACT same thing happens.

The vector (std::vector) is stored at object level in a class that contains the main methods.

Here is my function that needs to run on the event:

```
bool CAMMonitoredExtension::LogEvent(const CAMTelephoneEventNotification &camten) {
CAMCall *camCall = NULL;

camCall = GetCallFromNotification(camten);
if (camCall == NULL) {  // Call not found - this is a new call
    CString strNumber;
    strNumber.Format(_T("%s"),camten.m_tcNumber);
    if (strNumber == _T("")) {
        // No phone number, abort
        return false;
    }

    bool bCreateNewIfInvalid = true;
    if (!bCreateNewIfInvalid) { return false;   }

    // Create a new call
    //CAMCall camCallNew(m_strExtension);

    camCall = new CAMCall(m_strExtension);

    camCall->m_uniqueCallID = camten.m_tcCallID; // Identifies call for future runnings of this function.
    camCall->m_strTelephoneNumber = camten.m_tcNumber;
    camCall->m_codtTimeStarted = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
    if (!camCall->Save()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Put this call into the vector and then set the pointer to the reference to that.
    m_vActiveCalls.push_back(camCall);
}
}
```

Here is the GetCallFromNotification() function:

```
CAMCall* CAMMonitoredExtension::GetCallFromNotification(const CAMTelephoneEventNotification &camteNotification) {
if (m_vActiveCalls.size() == 0 ) {
    return NULL;
}

return m_vActiveCalls.back();
}
```

CAMCall class declaration:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CAMCall  
{
public:
    CAMCall(CString strExtension);
    //~CAMCall();

    CAMCall( const CAMCall& rhs );
    CAMCall& operator= (const CAMCall& rhs);
    void CloneFrom(const CAMCall &rhs);
private:
    CAMTrace m_trace;

// properties
public:
    int m_nRowID;

    LPCTSTR m_uniqueCallID;

    CString m_strExtension;
    CString m_strTelephoneNumber;

    COleDateTime m_codtTimeStarted;
    COleDateTime m_codtTimeFinished;

// methods
public:
    bool LogEvent(enumAMTelephoneCallStatus eamtCallStatus);

};
```

CAMCall class implementation:

```
    CAMCall::CAMCall(CString strExtension)
    :   m_nRowID(-1),
        m_uniqueCallID(_T("DEFAULT CALLID")),
        m_strExtension(strExtension),
        m_strTelephoneNumber(_T("")),
        m_codtTimeStarted(COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime()),
        m_codtTimeFinished((DATE)0)
{

}

CAMCall::CAMCall( const CAMCall& rhs )
{
    try
    {
    CloneFrom( rhs );
    }

    catch(...)
    {
    }
}

CAMCall& CAMCall::operator=(const CAMCall &rhs)
{
    try
    {
    if ( &rhs != this )
    {
        CloneFrom( rhs );
    }
    return *this;
    }

    catch(...)
    {
        CAMCall temp(_T(""));
        return temp;
    }
}

void CAMCall::CloneFrom(const CAMCall &rhs)
{
    m_nRowID = rhs.m_nRowID;
    m_uniqueCallID = rhs.m_uniqueCallID;
    m_strExtension = rhs.m_strExtension;
    m_strTelephoneNumber = rhs.m_strTelephoneNumber;
    m_codtTimeStarted = rhs.m_codtTimeStarted;
    m_codtTimeFinished = rhs.m_codtTimeFinished;
}
```

Comment: Anything could be going wrong. To pinpoint the mistake, we need a testable example.

Comment: The code is needed.  Without it being posted, the rest of us will be guessing at what is happening and the suggestions to resolve.

Comment: Sorry, was in the process of getting the code just thought I'd dump the question out first on the off-chance. Relevant functions above.

Comment: You should post the CAMCall class.

Comment: Is `CAMCall` a user defined object or structure?  Also, the `m_vActiveCalls` vector is configured to be empty when the `CAMMonitoredExtension` instance is created by its constructor?  Are there any other `push_back` calls on the vector?  How many instances of the `CAMMonitoredExtension` object are in use?

Comment: Ok CAMCall class added.

Yes, m_vActiveCalls is initialised as vector<CAMCall*>() in the intitialisation list. There is only one instance of the CAMMonitoredExtension object but could feasibly be more. There are no other push_back() calls.

Comment: `If, after immediately push_back()ing the object I get it with back(), then I can print out the properties fine. However, the second time the function runs, it's getting the properties as empty strings (they are all strings).`  So is the problem with vector, or with your objects having changed strings?  In other words, you're saying that the vector itself is OK, the pointer values are seemingly OK, it's that the strings within the objects are empty?

Comment: When running the function the second time it can see that the vector size is 1, rather than 0, so the pointer remains in there. I am losing either the object or the properties, I suppose. This is a windows service on a different computer so I can't really run any debugging on it right nwo.

Comment: Why is it that one member in your CAMCall class is an LPCTSTR? If it were just a CString, then you would not need a user-defined copy assignment nor copy constructor (assuming that CAMTrace is copyable).  Speaking of -- what exactly is CAMTrace?  You failed to copy it within your copy constructor and assignment operator.  Missing members involved in these functions is a cause for suspicion.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Why would I not require a copy constructor to pass CStrings? How do I know if it is copyable?

Comment: CString provides a built in copy constructor and assignment operator which is transparent to you, whereas the LPCTSTR is simply a pointer which you have to manually deep copy.

Comment: @user1014679 CString's are copyable by themselves. They have proper copy semantics. My guess is that you've written a bogus copy constructor and assignment operator (or CloneFrom). See my last comments. You are missing members within that function, causing copies to be not copies.  Writing copy constructors and assignment operators that really do half-baked "copies" can produce very hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Oh I asked a previous question as to why I was losing CString values and the answer was I needed a copy constructor.... And you can see my copy constructor, does it not contain all values?

Comment: Also, do not put try/catch in your copy constructor, and worse, return a bogus copy "temp".  Here is the simple reason -- a copy constructor and assignment operator's job is to do one thing -- make copies.  Nothing more, nothing less.  You decided to put business logic within these functions.  That is a non-starter in my book.  The reason is that the compiler can make copies without intervention from the programmer, making the operation not 100% under your control.  Therefore you should be concentrating only on one thing in those functions, again *making copies*.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't write these particular copy constructors so I was unaware as to best practices.

Comment: FYI, thank you, changing the data type to CString fixed it. I have no idea why the copy constructor wasn't handling it, or why the last time I had this problem my CStrings seemed to require copy constructors, but now it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: To help facilitate understanding, Review: [What are TCHAR, WCHAR, LPSTR, LPWSTR, LPCTSTR (etc.)?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc).  I would say that even though the LPCTSTR represents a constant pointer to a TCHAR string, the initialization with the string: `DEFAULT CALLID` caused memory overrun inside the `CAMCall` class.  Then when allocating a new CAMCall element, unpredictable results occur that trash memory and/or the stack and/or class data members.

Comment: Oh haha I forgot I left that in - I just put `DEFAULT CALLID` in temporarily do see if it was returning blank or the default value (default is actually blank). Would that solution still apply to a blank value?